# SQL- Current quarter data has to be truncated and reloaded but the previous quarter should remain untouched

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Say there are two quarters Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
 Q1 is 20160331 and Q2 is 20160630.
I need to write a query to load the table in such a way that every time I load the table, I need to delete the given quarter records and reload them with the given quarter records.
Once I move from Q1 to Q2 I should not touch Q1 records and only the Q2 records should be truncated and reloaded.
`@UseDate` is the variable which has the current given quarter date
`QuarterKey` has the quarter date for which the records are loaded.
`Stg` has the current given quarter data. `Stg` is always a truncate reload.
Fact should delete the current quarter date and reload it.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Fact]') AND type in (N'U') 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Fact]) >0)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Fact] 
WHERE  (SELECT MAX(QuarterKey) FROM [Fact] ) = @UseDate
END
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact]
SELECT * from stg
Where (SELECT MAX(QuarterKey) FROM [Stg] ) = @UseDate
```

With this query when I’m loading Q2, Q1 data is getting deleted.
It’s a minor fix from what I think but I’m unable to fix it.
Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your @usedate has values like 20160331 then we need to extract the quarter from that and then delete the records from fact which has the same quarter .

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Fact] 
WHERE  Datepart(Quarter,Quarterkey) = datepart(Quarter,@useDate);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact]
SELECT * from stg
Where Datepart(Quarter,Quarterkey) not in (select 
datepart(Quarter,@UseDate);
```

It will be more performance efficient if the @UseDate is already having the extracted quarter data

Comment: This query is not loading the fact table in the first run. The @UseDate has the whole date key that is coming from the fact table. Ex: UseDate = '20160331' in first run UseDate = '20160630' in the second run. Again in 3rd run if UseDate = '20160630'. it should delete the '20160630' records from the fact table and load with the new '20160630' records.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I got the solution i just had to remove the where clause in the end. So irrespective of what it would always load the table because those rows are being deleted.

Comment: yeah since your stg table has only the current quarter data removing the where clause would be a more practical solution